# Trying to use Mobile Framework: Gliders in my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, frameworks

I'm currently trying to adapt my currently in-development jquery-mobile web application to use the navigational structure from this mobile template called Gliders, and I'm having some issues.

http://www.enableds.com/products/gliders/

I've been following their FAQ in order to incorporate the page structure, as well as the left sidebar in an attempt to get their navigational structure working, but I keep getting the following error in tons of my scripts:

**$ is not a function**

This is what was happening when I kept my current version of jquery in (which is 1.11.3); and when I switched to their version (which is 1.8.2), I get this error:

**$(...).sketch is not a function**

Though even if I comment my sketch functions out, the left sidebar isn't showing up at all.

Does anyone have experience with using templates like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was because I was using a different version of jQuery than the version that was in the application.